# What is ElasticSearch and how can it be usefull?

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene, search-engine, information-retrieval

i'm new to Search Engines, I'm working with Apache Lucene and Terrier and I found out ElasticSearch.

is there someone that can explain what kind of things i can do with it?
How does it differ from the retrieval functionalities of Lucene?

Answer (score 0):

http://solr-vs-elasticsearch.com/ - a very comprehencive feature smackdown.